# Why does cabal think I need an old library?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Just so I can start fresh, I removed `package.conf.d` at `~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.2`.

When I try to install `numeric-prelude`, cabal tries to install an old version of `mtl`, even though I have checked all of the dependencies and the newest `mtl` can be used.

Here's a smaller example demonstrating a (hopefully) related problem:

```
$ cabal install QuickCheck parsec --dry-run
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed (use -v for more details):
mtl-2.1.3.1 (latest: 2.2.1)
primitive-0.5.3.0
random-1.0.1.1
text-1.1.1.3
parsec-3.1.5
tf-random-0.5
QuickCheck-2.7.5
```

but install either on their own:

```
$ cabal install QuickCheck --dry-run
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed (use -v for more details):
primitive-0.5.3.0
random-1.0.1.1
tf-random-0.5
QuickCheck-2.7.5

$ cabal install parsec --dry-run
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed (use -v for more details):
text-1.1.1.3
transformers-0.4.1.0
mtl-2.2.1
parsec-3.1.5
```

and neither needs `mtl-2.1.3.1`!

The problem is similar with `numeric-prelude`: I have installed all of the listed dependencies  without issue using `mtl-2.2`. Then when I try to install `numeric-prelude`, cabal tries to install an old version of `mtl`.

I assumed that even if I had borked my cabal pacakges, removing the user `package.conf.d` would fix this. So is my cabal still borked, or is there something else going on here?

Comment: can you try `cabal install QuickCheck parsec --dry-run --constraint="mtl==2.2.1"` ?

Comment: This is probably done because you have already installed another package, such as `text` and it built against mtl 2.1.3.1 - to avoid re-installing text it re-uses the old version against-which you built a previous package.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson As I mentioned though, this problem persists after I remove the user `package.conf.d` file, so there are no existing user packages. I'm assuming the global packages don't depend on `mtl` since I didn't install any global packages myself...

Comment: Also, that doesn't explain why the dependencies would be different when installing two packages together vs separately.

Comment: @bennofs Thanks for the tip. When I tried that, cabal wanted to install an ancient version of `parsec`, even though the latest version has no constraints on the `mtl` version.

Comment: @Eric can you keep adding --constraint flags until it chooses the build plan you want? That will tell you if the plan is possible (it will give an error otherwise)

Answer (score 4):

I can "fix" this on my machine by saying:

```
cabal install QuickCheck parsec --constraint="transformers == 0.4.*"
```

The problem in this case is that `QuickCheck` depends on transformers, and the preference is to choose a version you already have installed, which is `transformers-0.3.0.0`. But this choice of `transformers` is now inconsistent with choosing the latest `mtl`. Now Cabal has to make a choice which of two preferences to violate (either pick a later version of `transformers` to build `QuickCheck` with, or pick an older version of `mtl`). It randomly chooses one, and in this case, this happens to be not the one you want ... Adding the additional constraint helps.

#### Edit

For `numeric-prelude`, the situation is slightly different. The latest version of `numeric-prelude` depends on `storable-record`, which explicitly depends on `transformers < 0.4`. But `numeric-prelude` also depends on `parsec`, which depends on `mtl`. So you simply cannot use it with the latest `mtl`.

Comment: I wonder if the underlying problem is that GHC-7.8.2 relies on `transformers-0.3.0.0`. I tried to [download a nightly build](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download) to see if this was fixed, but the [link](http://darcs.haskell.org/ghcBuilder/uploads/) is dead.